# What is differences between ./yourscript.sh and sh yourscript.sh

Tags: linux, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Whats the difference between running a shell script as ./script.sh and sh script.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468132/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-shell-script-as-script-sh-and-sh-script)

When you run script like `./yourscript.sh` and `sh yourscript.sh` whats is the difference between this?

Answer (score 0):

When running the script ./yourscript.sh, the file must be marked as executable and you must declare at the top of your script the shell which you wish to use.  E.g.:

```
#!/bin/sh
<your code here>
```

When just using sh yourscript.sh, you do not need these requirements.

Comment: do or don't need? Good luck to all.