# How to format a number in bash, possibly with printf?

Tags: bash, printf

This so simple script is failing :

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
printf -v fn "%05d" $n
echo $fn
```

with

```
3: printf: Illegal option -v
```

WHY !!! (ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between running a shell script as ./script.sh and sh script.sh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468132/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-shell-script-as-script-sh-and-sh-script)

Comment: You are right, i invoqued the script with sh on ubuntu. Didn't now about the difference. Thank you Joe !!

Comment: !!! OMG !!! That is correct!  On Mac OS X, "sh" and "bash" are the same thing, and invoking with `sh` makes no difference.  But on Ubuntu, I get the exact behavior you get!

Comment: Debian and its derivatives use `dash` as their default shell. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh.

Comment: @Flortify It's even a little more complicated than that. On OSX, `sh` and `bash` are the same *by default*. But depending on your `PATH` and whether you have installed a more recent version of `bash`, they may differ. For me `bash` is `4.3.18(1)-release` and `sh` is `3.2.48(1)-release`.

Comment: @Telemachus, you seem to be saying "if you change the configuration of your system, then your system may behave differently", which seems like a truism.  And the OP didn't mention a non-stock system configuration.  But, yes, a non-stock system configuration would be an important thing to include in a question when posting here.

Comment: @Flortify Fair enough. I was just pointing out that your `PATH` can affect things as well. There's a reason, for example, that people use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` rather than assuming `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: @Telemachus Another good point! Use `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Joe, this appears to be a duplicate of [Whats the difference between running a shell script as ./script.sh and sh script.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468132/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-shell-script-as-script-sh-and-sh-script).

Per @Telemachus, Debian and its derivatives use dash as their default shell. See http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh for more information.

Here's what I see on an Ubuntu system:

```
$ ls -lF `which sh`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug 15  2012 /bin/sh -> dash*
$ ls -lF `which bash`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 959168 Mar 30  2013 /bin/bash*
```

That explains why I was not able to reproduce the issue on Mac OS X 10.8.5.  I **did** reproduce it on Ubuntu by invoking the script with `sh` instead of `bash`.

I'm leaving the rest of my answer in place since it demonstrates some steps you might take to troubleshoot the problem.

Can you check your version of bash?

```
$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
```

Does this even work?

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
printf -v fn "%05d" $n
echo $fn
```

Check the type of the name `printf`?

```
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
$ function printf { echo "giggle" ; }
giggle
$ type printf
printf is a function
printf () 
{ 
    echo "giggle"
}
giggle
$
```

Check the builtin help for the `printf` builtin?

```
$ help printf
help printf

printf: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
    printf formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT. FORMAT
    is a character string which contains three types of objects: plain
    characters, which are simply copied to standard output, character escape
    sequences which are converted and copied to the standard output, and
    format specifications, each of which causes printing of the next successive
    argument.  In addition to the standard printf(1) formats, %b means to
    expand backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument, and %q
    means to quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input.
    If the -v option is supplied, the output is placed into the value of the
    shell variable VAR rather than being sent to the standard output.
```

Has the builtin `printf` been replaced by a definition from somewhere else?  Here's a function I use for checking the definition of names in the shell:

```
list () 
{ 
    if [[ 0 == $# ]]; then
        Log "";
        Log "FUNCTIONS:";
        Log "----------";
        declare -F;
        Log "";
        Log "EXPORTS:";
        Log "--------";
        export -p;
        Log "";
        Log "PRINTENV:";
        Log "--------";
        printenv;
    else
        while [[ ! -z "$1" ]]; do
            local name="$1";
            shift;
            if ! alias "${name}" 2> /dev/null; then
                if ! declare -f "${name}"; then
                    if ! help "${name}" 2> /dev/null; then
                        if ! which "${name}"; then
                            Log "Not found: '${name}'";
                        fi;
                    fi;
                fi;
            fi;
        done;
    fi
}
```

Here's the output when I run this in a fresh shell:

```
$ list printf
printf: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
    printf formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT. FORMAT
    [… snip …]
```

But if I redefine `printf`, it will show the definition:

```
$ function printf { echo "kibble" ; }
kibble
$ printf
kibble
kibble
$ list printf
printf () 
{ 
    echo "kibble"
}
kibble
$
```

I am curious to hear what's really going on here!!!

I like the other answer's suggestion to try invoking the script explicitly w/ bash:

```
$ bash myscript.sh
```

Here's what I see on an Ubuntu server:

```
$ uname -a
Linux rack 3.11.0-17-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 21:52:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat > dme.sh
#!/bin/bash
n=1
printf -v fn "%05d" $n
echo $fn
$ chmod +x ./dme.sh
$ ./dme.sh
00001
$ bash dme.sh
00001
$ sh dme.sh
dme.sh: 3: printf: Illegal option -v
```

Comment: Note that you can find information about `printf`, and other functions, via `type`. `type printf` yields (normally) `printf is a shell builtin`.

Comment: @konsolebox I have edited the answer to put the simplest answer first.  I preserved the rest of the answer as a demonstration of how one might troubleshoot similar problems.  I think that has value.  "Give a man a fish, you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish, you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: I'm sorry but even first parts of your answer is not simple enough. I would actually give Joe's answer as a candidate for a simple answer even though it was an obvious derivative answer from mine who posted it after JulienFr replied to me. I actually found it unnecessary as my point was already obvious. There was no need to give a tangent.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using a version of Bash not supporting `-v` option yet. Try running `bash --version`. It should be 3.1 or newer.

Also, make sure you do run your script with bash. Try explicitly calling `bash script.sh`.

Comment: bash --version gives
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 2):

You're running the script as an argument to `/bin/sh`, like this:

```
$ sh script.sh 
script.sh: 3: printf: Illegal option -v
```

which ignores the `#!` line. Run it as:

```
$ ./script.sh
00001
```

instead.

Comment: Maybe add a mention of `dash` as `/bin/sh` on Debian and its derivatives and this link? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh (I'll remove my answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

As other answers tell you that older BASH version versions don't support `printf -v` but here is what you can do that in older BASH to set `fn`:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
fn=$(printf "%05d" "$n")
echo "$fn"
```