# Why it runs different for source and sh calling in shell

Tags: shell

My shell `a.sh` script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $ret maybe from database or pipe,whatever it likes:
ret="cnt
1"

echo -e $ret
```

and calling in different ways produces different results:

```
$ sh a.sh
cnt 1
$ source a.sh
cnt
1
$
```

How can I get the same output under `sh` and `source`?

Comment: running a script and sourcing it are different things. Also, you need to quote `echo`.

Comment: thanks @fedorqui. that means `echo -e "$ret"`
I know `sh` or `source` are different calling way, details we can see [Whats the difference between running a shell script as ./script.sh and sh script.sh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468132/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-shell-script-as-script-sh-and-sh-script)

Comment: Which shell are you using?  It appears it must be `zsh`; only that shell (out of Bash, Dash, Korn, and zsh tried) produces the two-line output when the script you show is sourced; the others produce a single line of output (and Bash run as `sh` adds `-e` to the output).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the same output under `sh` and `source`?

you need to quote `echo`. – fedorqui

thanks @fedorqui. that means `echo -e "$ret"` – tonylee0329

Exactly, quoting `echo`'s argument is the way to adjust the difference between the two shells' `echo`s.